# Foreign key column allows to insert value that is not in referenced column

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys

I have to tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `artist` (
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    `gender`    TEXT NOT NULL,
    `city`  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
);
```

and

```
create table artwork(
    title text,
    location text,
    artist text,
    primary key (title, artist),
    foreign key (artist) references artist(name)
    );
```

'artist' column in 'artwork' table allows me to insert data that is not in referenced column.

> The FOREIGN KEY constraint also prevents invalid data from being
>   inserted into the foreign key column, because it has to be one of the
>   values contained in the table it points to.
>   (c) W3school

Have I done it the wrong way ?

Comment: name is of type `TEXT` and it is a primary key, you can have this column as key only if you specify the length.
your create table statement will give a error.

Comment: it doesn't give error. Tables are created fine, i can see them.

Comment: which version of mysql ? are these commands run from some other application. there might be some default length used in that case.

Comment: I'm using SQLIte, but thanks for your comment it'll help me in the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you using SQLite? 
if so, you need to first run

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

while SQLite does offer foreign key constraint, it is disabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Text columns are not supported in foreign key constraints because they cannot be indexed. According to official docs:

> Index prefixes on foreign key columns are not supported. One
>   consequence of this is that BLOB and TEXT columns cannot be included
>   in a foreign key because indexes on those columns must always include
>   a prefix length.

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html